# How to get forex data from iframe widget using javascript

Tags: javascript, iframe, forex

I'm working on forex programming. My coding work find with demo datasource. Anyway, I found free forex data widget (iframe) called by javascript as below.

```
<script src="https://1forge.com/widget-cdn/forex-ticker/main.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<div id="forex-ticker"></div> 
<script>
    ForexTicker.init(
    {
        pairs: ["EURUSD", "USDJPY", "GBPUSD", "USDCHF", "EURCHF", "AUDUSD"],
        theme: "dark", //this can be "light" or "dark" 
        margin: "10px",
        width: "100%",
        height: "600px",
  });
</script>
```

My silly question, Is it possible to get these iframe's data using javascript?. Any advice or guidance on this would be greatly appreciated, Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the iframe is on another domain, then by default you have no access to anything found inside. You will need to see if `ForexTicker` offers some sort of API to access things from within.

Comment: Dear Madara Uchiha, Thanks for info.